# slow sql query C#

Tags: c#, sql, performance, linq

I have a sql query that takes forever to run. I know where the problem is but I don't know how to solve it.

Here my code:

```
var result = context.Persons.OrderByDescending(x => x.PersonId);
var response = result.Where(x => x.IsProvider.Equals(false) && x.Obsolete.Equals(false) && x.Locked.Equals(false) && x.IsCustomer.Equals(true));

var list = new List<ICustomerHead>();

foreach (var customer in response)
{
    if (!customer.PersonType.Equals(2))
    {
        list.Add(customer.ToSingleCustomerHead());
    }
}

foreach (var customer in list) //This loop is the problem, because it will make a new db connection for every customer
{
    var companyResult = context.Companies.SingleOrDefault(x => x.CompanyId.Equals(customer.Id));

    if (companyResult != null)
        customer.Email = companyResult.StandardEMail;
}

return list;
```

The second loop is where the delay is. It's because it will make a new db connection for every customer. So how can I make this faster?

Please help  :)

Comment: Why are you comparing company ID with Customer ID?

Comment: Those are connected with each other. I know it's not the best solution.

Comment: Could you store `context.Companies` somewhere first, and then just filter in the loop later?

Comment: Sure, will that make it faster? And will it be a performance issue if it is to many companies?

Comment: Your performance problem is not due to new connections but due to round-trips and per-query LINQ overhead. Reduce the number of queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple - if you have a list of IDs, and you want one select query that gets all the Companies with an ID in that list you need to use .Contains (which translates to `IN` in SQL )

Heres how:

```
var idList = list.Select(x => x.Id);
// create a query that just gets the required emails and companyIds.
var emails = context.Companies.Where(x => idList.Contains(x.CompanyId))
                              .Select(x => new {x.CompanyId, x.StandardEmail});
// execute the query (with .ToList() ) 
// and then iterate through the results, setting e-mail address on the list items
emails.ToList().ForEach(
  x => list.First(y => y.Id == x.CompanyId).Email = x.StandardEmail
);
```

To be honest though I'd probably just do a single query that gets your customers together with their e-mail addresses in 1 hit.

eg:

```
var list = new List<ICustomerHead>();
var query = from p in context.Persons
            join c in context.Companies on p.CompanyId equals c.CompanyId
            where p.IsProvider.Equals(false) 
                  && p.Obsolete.Equals(false) 
                  && p.Locked.Equals(false) 
                  && p.IsCustomer.Equals(true)
                  && !p.PersonType.Equals(2) // not sure why this was separate before?
            select new {p, c.StandardEmail};

foreach(var item in query.ToList()) //ToList() causes the query to execute
{
  var customer = item.p.ToSingleCustomerHead(); //assume this is an extension method you've added?
  customer.Email = item.StandardEMail;
  list.Add(customer);
}
```

Comment: That worked, it shouldn't be && p.PersonType.Equals(2), it should be && !p.PersonType.Equals(2). But thanks a lot :D

Comment: edited to correct that - and glad its working for you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming company as a related entity you can use Include company in first query

Add this reference to use Include lambda (using System.Data.Entity;)

```
var response = result.Include(x=>x.Companies).Where(x => x.IsProvider.Equals(false) && x.Obsolete.Equals(false) && x.Locked.Equals(false) && x.IsCustomer.Equals(true));
```

Add

```
 foreach (var customer in response)
    {
        if (!customer.PersonType.Equals(2))
        {
            var c =customer.ToSingleCustomerHead();

            if (customer.Companies !=null && customer.Companies.FirstOrDefaultOrDefault() != null)
                c.Email = companyResult.StandardEMail;

            list.Add(c);
        }
    }
```

Note: FirstOrDefaultOrDefault is faster than SingleOrDefault bacasuse singleOrDefault check for uninque values.

Comment: Okey, but I can't get the Include to work.
When I try "using System.Data.Entity;" it says Cannot resolve symbol 'Entity'

Comment: Add a reference to "system.data.entity" (search the exact name in framework element)